# How to find implied sentence parts in flash news

Tags: syntax

The following is a flash news from テレ朝

沖縄県　「緊急事態宣言」政府への要請を正式決定

Two questions:

1. What particles are implied after Okinawa prefecture and after quoted "declaration of emergency state"?
2. Since the government is followed by へ, の cannot be the subject marker, then who on earth is calling for the government to declare the state of emergency?

Bonus question: are there general rules how to analyze flash news?

Answer (score 2):

It should be read as 沖縄県**が**「緊急事態宣言」**の**政府への要請を正式決定. Note that 「緊急事態宣言」の modifies 要請, not 政府. It means 沖縄県が「緊急事態宣言」を政府に要請することを正式に決定した.

In many cases, the first part is the subject and the last part refers to something it did, or was done if the noun at the end is normally used in the passive, such as 逮捕.

Comment: It still does not answer the question "who is officially requesting". Who is it in Okinawa calling for the government actions? Is it a general assembly, results of the poll, or someone else? It is unclear what official body (正式) makes the request.

Comment: @user1602: The headline says nothing about it. It would be assumed to be the head of the prefecture, the governor. I don’t think this is unique to Japanese headlines. How would you read a headline like “Tokyo resumes talks with Beijing”? Who in Tokyo will talk to who in Beijing?

Comment: Tokyo implies The Japanese Government, this case is no-brainer. The governor of Okinawa IS the government - he cannot call on himself to declare the emergency state. My knowledge of the Japanese society is not enough to determine who officially decided to appeal to the government in the example of this post.

Comment: @user1602 Who in the Japanese government?

Comment: It will the ministry of the foreign affairs who will talk to Beijing.

Comment: @user1602 The Japan Times has this headline: “Okinawa to seek COVID-19 state of emergency” This English headline gives no more information about your doubt than the Japanese headline you asked about. You would probably be asking the same question. Then, it’s not a question about the language. I would suggest you ask somewhere else.

Comment: @user1602: Your statement “The governor of Okinawa IS the government” is false if you meant the central government by “the government”. Okinawa prefecture is a local government and local governments may make requests to the central government, if this is what you were not getting.

Comment: I am not a lawyer and do not understand well the Japanese government structure. If you change your answer clarifying that the local government of Okinawa officially decided to call for the central government to declare the state of emergency, I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: @user1602: You have learned all you needed to know about your question, and some more, as you now know who is the one seeking in the English headline “Okinawa to seek COVID-19 state of emergency”, too, without becoming a lawyer. And you are welcome.

Comment: 沖縄県では、政府への「緊急事態宣言」発出要請を正式決定

Comment: @samhana: That’s also possible. I would suggest you post it as your own answer. It should attract the “who in Okinawa?” question even more. I’m done with it.

Comment: The prefectures aren't the ones who declare the state of emergency, the national government does, right? Is all of this just coming from thinking that Okinawa has the power to declare a state of emergency for themselves?

Comment: That's right. In US a state has the power to declare a state of emergency. Also the term "government" refers to both local and federal entities, and has to be disambiguated.

Comment: What 政府 means was never part of the question or the subsequent comments. The subject is 沖縄県 and that answers the question.